# could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could notextract ResultSet delete not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Well, what I'm doing is only deleting a Pais in a REST API but for some reason I get all this error trace (I have to say Pais, I only have it related to the Documentos and Moneda table, and in one of the errors it says I don't know than from the Remesatable, when it is not directly related to Pais):

**PaisServiceImpl:**

```java
public void getEliminaPais(Long pais_id) {
    boolean existePais = paisRepo.existsById(pais_id);

    if (existePais) {
        //  paisRepo.deleteById(pais_id);
        paisRepo.delete(paisRepo.findById(pais_id).get()); //HERE FAILS
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pais con id ".concat(String.valueOf(existePais).concat(" no existe")));
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
     
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: reference to the entry of the FROM clause for the table "remittance" not valid
      Hint: There is an entry for the "remesa" table, but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
      Position: 591
```

**Pais.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Documento> documento;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Moneda moneda;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Feriado> feriados;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Corresponsable> corresponsables;
```

**Documento.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "remesa_id", nullable = true)
private Remesa remesa;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "moneda_id", nullable = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Moneda moneda;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais_id", nullable = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Pais pais;
```

**Remesa.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "remesa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Documento> documento;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "remesa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private EnvioRemesa envio_id;
```

**Moneda.java**

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais", nullable = true)
@JsonProperty("pais")
private Pais pais;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "moneda", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Corresponsable> corresponsables;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "moneda", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Documento> documentos;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "moneda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Remesa remesa;
```

Comment: Add more details. What is the implementation of entity classes?

Comment: @M.Dudek i have edited the question with the entity relationships

Comment: Also it would be nice to have an english version of error

Comment: @IlyaSazonov i edited the question with english error

Comment: for some reason "remesa" is involved when i'm deleting a Pais

Comment: Well now it's seems like DELETE is not working on Pais,Documento,Moneda and Remesa. These 4 relations are connected so maybe here is the probelm..

Comment: Are your collections initialized with `new` anywhere?

Comment: No, they are not @M.Dudek

Comment: @efejdlek So you have an undefined reference to the collection when you try to retrieve the `Set`

Comment: Could you turn sql logging on, so that we could see query, which hibernate generates?

Answer (score 0):

Delete method expects the ID(primary key) as input

you can use the following code

```
paisRepo.findById(pais_id).orElseThrow(()->new YourCustomeException(Message)));
```

If the above statement doesn't fail... you go ahead and delete the object

```
paisRepo.deleteById(pais_id);
```

Comment: not working for me , i'm having the same error